# Spark in Scala - Setting number of CPU

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to limit my CPU usage, but I got this strange result : when I try to limit to 3 CPU, I still get a sparck Context with [*] master :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without more information my guess would be that you are doing this from inside of the spark shell. That means the master has already been set and will be used. Note that the call is `getOrCreate`, which means it will create only if it cannot get something already there.

Comment: I am indeed into Toree notebook

Answer (score 0):

That's because you already have one SparkSession object.

If there is active session in thread context, then this session will be used. Your notebook has one attached session and that's why `getOrCreate` is returning existing SparkSession.

Check in your logs, probably you have:

```
Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
```

Then you can clean active sessions:

```
SparkSession.clearActiveSession()
```

But in notebooks it is not recommended as it can cause errors in other notebooks on your servers